# Deleting and updating mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

I got such problem. I clear all fields of record from database with this script:

```
  mysql_query("UPDATE users SET obiekt = NULL, typ =NULL, adres=NULL, lat=NULL, lng =NULL,  kod=NULL, poczta=NULL, tels=NULL, telk=NULL, email=NULL, www=NULL, imie=NULL, nazwisko=NULL,  qchnia = NULL,  qchnia2 = NULL,  qchnia3 = NULL, gwiazdki = NULL, cena =NULL,   region = NULL, komentarz=NULL WHERE login = '$login' ");
```

It works properly. But if I want to enter new data for this user, they doesn't appear. I put new data with this:

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE IF NOT EXIST users SET obiekt ='$obiekt', typ ='$typ', adres='$adres', lat='$lat', lng ='$lng',  kod='$kod', poczta='$poczta', tels='$tels', telk='$telk', email='$email', www='$www', imie='$imie', nazwisko='$nazwisko',  qchnia = '$qchnia', region = '$region', komentarz='$komentarz' WHERE login = '$login' ");
```

Also have to mention, that only data which appear is data which is send with select form:

```
  <select id ="gwiazdki" name ="gwiazdki">
<option value="option0">bez gwiazdek</option>
<option value="option1">1 gwiazdka</option>
<option value="option2">2 gwiazdki</option>
<option value="option3">3 gwiazdki</option>
<option value="option4">4 gwiazdki</option>
<option value="option5">5 gwiazdek</option>
</select>
```

How to make new data being sent correctly? If I check what data are send (print_r($_post)) 
it returns correct values, but than ,as I wrote , doesn't write it to db. Help needed.

P.S. I use MyIsam

Comment: To add new rows, you use `INSERT`, not `UPDATE`.

Comment: You are using "IF NOT EXISTS" but the row exists, its just null. Replace first query with: `"DELETE FROM users WHERE login = '$login'"`

Comment: There is no `IF NOT EXISTS` option in MySQL `UPDATE` syntax. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this for update;

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET obiekt ='$obiekt', typ ='$typ', adres='$adres', lat='$lat', lng ='$lng',  kod='$kod', poczta='$poczta', tels='$tels', telk='$telk', email='$email', www='$www', imie='$imie', nazwisko='$nazwisko',  qchnia = '$qchnia', region = '$region', komentarz='$komentarz' WHERE login = '$login' ");
```

`IF NOT EXISTS` is used while db or table creation not data creation. Refer here:

[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-database.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET obiekt ='$obiekt', typ ='$typ', adres='$adres', lat='$lat', lng ='$lng',  kod='$kod', poczta='$poczta', tels='$tels', telk='$telk', email='$email', www='$www', imie='$imie', nazwisko='$nazwisko',  qchnia = '$qchnia', region = '$region', komentarz='$komentarz' WHERE login = '$login' ");
```